# wireless network connection

Tags: 12.04, wireless

wireless option not showing up in Network, or additional drivers.
Dell inspirion 220 with Ubuntu 12.04 lts

network card identified in Terminal:

```
product: bcm 4318 ... configuration driver=wl latency=64
```

have attempted to install b43 firmware update. still no connnection option.
new to Ubuntu, old hat at Mac/PC
kat

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have the incorrect driver. Please run:

```
lspci -nn
```

Is your Broadcom wireless device identifier 14e4:4318? If so, please do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Reboot and tell us if it's working. If that is not your device identifier, post it here and we'll propose a solution.